# Serving mysql data to a flip html pdf or downloadable pdf

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, pdf, pdf-generation, amazon-aurora

I have a web application running of AWS MySQL Aurora database.

If I want to use that data to create PDF reports, the results of which need to be served as a fliphtml pdf (or any other related service), how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be done so many ways.
follow the below steps.
1) 
Build a spring rest service which will call the database
2) create the jasper template and fill with data.
3) render the report in browser as pdf